# Get accounts configured count in android device

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, accountmanager, google-account, android-account

I want to get configured accounts count without any user intervention. I was using `AccountManager.getAccounts()` function before API level 26 and was working fine.

But as GET_ACCOUNTS permission behavior has been changed in API 26, it will prompt user the list of accounts on device before getting access to them. `accountManager.newChooseAccountIntent()`

My requirement is to check if any account is configured on account on which I have to perform tasks(No user interaction). Is there any way I can check(no. of accounts) the same other than prompting user to choose accounts.

I have already referred to the below tickets but couldn't find any way to do the same without user consent:

[AccountManager.getAccounts() not working in targetsdk > 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49829398/accountmanager-getaccounts-not-working-in-targetsdk-23?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Pick an email using AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174259/pick-an-email-using-accountpicker-newchooseaccountintent)

Comment: This is not and should not be possible. If there would be a way to do this in Android 8+ without explicit user consent, Google would most likely treat it as a security issue and fix it. Android's goal here is to protect the user. Basically, you are asking to use e.g. the microphone without asking the user. That's not what a user wants usually :)